# how to mount file type

Tags: mount, filesystem, data-recovery, file-format, fdisk

I have recently imaged some floppy disks to img files. 
the disks had some bad blocks. 
So I am trying to figure out the File system type, 
so that i can mount, and repair the files.
I tried `$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/fd0` which returned nothing.

```
$ sudo file -Ls /dev/fd0
/dev/fd0: data
```

is data the FS type? 
How can I mount / repair this image type?

```
$ sudo file -Ls lisa1.img
    /dev/stdout: data
```

Comment: Are there any other clues with: sudo blkid /dev/fd0 ?

Comment: Are you talking about the images or an actual floppy? If you have already made the image files, why are you checking `/dev/fd0`? What does `file -Ls /path/to/floppy.img` return?

Comment: Do you think you could make one of these images available to us so we can try it out?

Answer (score 3):

Floppies are almost sure to be <del>VFAT</del>`msdos`, you can find out by running `file` on the actual image as I suggested in my comment:

```
file /path/to/floppy.img
```

However, that returns the file's *type* not the filesystem that the image contains. Filesystem image files are data and that's what `file` is telling you. I know that `file` will report the filesystem for `.iso` images but I don't know how it will deal with the ones you have.

Assuming they are indeed `msdos`, you can mount with

```
sudo mount -o loop -t msdos /path/to/floppy.img /mount/point
```

Comment: I have tried -o loop -t vfat I get error messages about incorrect FS type, and mtab

Comment: @j0h argh, my bad, that should be `file /path/to/floppy.img` the `-L` and `-s` are not needed and _might_ cause problems. Anyway, please [edit] your question and add the command you tried and the exact error message returned.

Comment: @j0h see updated answer, it's been way too long since I had to use a floppy.